# Laravel 5 - how to change route() and assets() url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I use the following helpers:

```
assets('css/app.css');
route('home');
```

..it generates this URL: "http://myapp.vagrant/css/app.css"

However, I want to change the URL to generate "http://192.168.1.134:8088" as, in my case, a network IP is what I need.

I can find where "myapp.vagrant" is set though. I've change Homestead.yaml and .env files, I've destroyed then `vagrant up` again. I've tried grep to locate where else this domain might be defined.

Any suggestions? The URL http://192.168.1.134:8088 is pointing correctly to the site but the urls that are generated are using the wrong URL (myapp.vagrant)

Btw here's my apache config file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:8088>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ProxyPass "/" "http://myapp.vagrant/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://myapp.vagrant/"
</VirtualHost>
```

So http://192.168.1.134 is the host machine, and I want port 8088 to point to http://myapp.vagrant/ (/etc/hosts points this domain to the vagrant IP) .. unless Laravel is picking up this domain from here?

Comment: try this `ProxyPreserveHost Off` in conf file and le'm know what is the result

Comment: if it would't work for you the you have to `ProxyPass "/" "http://192.168.1.134"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.1.134"`

Comment: Hi. `Off` is the default, but for my setup `ProxyPreserveHost On` works now. Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction anyway :)

Comment: Most Welcome..!

Answer (score 1):

you can use .env file to set it

`APP_URL=http://192.168.1.134:8088`

Comment: I've set this already. Vagrant up again, but still it's got the wrong domain.

Comment: Have you added `Listen 192.168.1.134:8088` to your virtual host configration file

Comment: I've added my apache config file if that helps.

Comment: Did you `php artisan cache:clean` after .env update ?